# undefined method in view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nomethoderror

I sorted my table following this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

I'm getting a `undefined method sortable' for #<#<Class:0x00000002f90c48>:0x00000002ba85b8>` when i call sortable.

index.html.erb:

```
<table class="issuesTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><%= sortable "title" %></th>
        <th>Desc</th>
        ...
```

application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
   end
 end
```

issues_controller.rb:

```
# GET /issues
# GET /issues.json
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

def index
  @issues = Issue.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end

...

private
  def sort_column
    Issue.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "title"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: its Rails 5.1.2

Comment: @Alberto please add complete error message and also content of index.html.erb

Comment: @Alberto please do also add definition of IssuesController

Comment: error

NoMethodError in Issues#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/app/views/issues/index.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `sortable' for #<#<Class:0x00000004164320>:0x0000000415c508>
Extracted source (around line #8):
6
7
8
9
10
11
              
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "title" %></th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>P</th>
      <th>Estado</th>

Comment: i can't put the complete code of because the is to much code in the post, here it is:
https://pastebin.com/pqsmp8wL
https://pastebin.com/LywUbyhy

Comment: @Alberto I think this should not have happened with the code that you have mentioned. Are you sure that you have saved all your files after editting files?  Also, according to error, it says that you are calling sortable on any object of some class, where as as per the code, you are calling helper method.

Comment: If you move the sortable method to issues_helper does it work?
Also just to be sure, check that you have saved changes on the application_helper as @AakashGupta said

Comment: i put it in issues_helper and the same error. Any other way yo make the same funcionality ? thanks @AakashGupta

Comment: Actually the way it is done is perfect. May be we can debug this using remote control or Team Viewer. You can contact me here https://www.facebook.com/aakashgupta96  @Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that the IDE he was using created issues for him and didn't update the helper files, so there was no function in the files.

After saving those files, the code executed perfectly.

So, **key to problem was saving the code** :P